# image is not getting loaded from the express static Folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, express, filepath

Images is getting loaded from the local Folder
But not from the uploads Folder which is declared static.

I have been trying to upload file from the browser,
The image is uploaded sucessfully and saved successfully
But while rendering the images from the uploads folder is not getting rendered

[image: This is how the first image which is in src/public is rendered whereass the uploads/images are not rendered]

Sample Data from MongoDb Database

```
_id:1
...
image:"/images/mouse.jpg"
...

_id:2
...
image:"/uploads/image-1647229113730.jpeg"
...
```

Product Component

```
const Product = ({ product }) => {
  return (
    <Card className='my-3 p-3 rounded'>
      <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
        <Card.Img src={product.image} variant='top' />
      </Link>
      <Card.Body>
        ...
      </Card.Body>
    </Card>
  )
}

export default Product
```

The File herarchy is as follows

```
Repo
 | backend
   | server.js
 | frontend
   | public
     | images
        |mouse.jpg
 | uploads
   | image-1647229113730.jpeg
```

In server.js in the backend i have made the uploades folder static

```
const __dirname = path.resolve();
app.use("/uploads", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/uploads")));
```

My problem is simple ,

*/images/mouse.jpg is accessible |
/uploads/image-1647229113730.jpeg is not accessible*

though both are there in the projects folder why ?

Comment: To solve problems with static file serving using `express.static()`, we need three things: 1) The actual URL the browser is requesting or show us the generated HTML (not the template) for the image tag, 2) The location of the file on your server's hard disk containing the `express.static()` middleware call, 3) The location of the static file you're trying to server on your server's hard disk.  With these three pieces of information, we can offer a fix immediately.  It appears we are missing item #1 since we don't know what URL the browser is requesting when it tries to load the image.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable information, as i have done everything in the local host , the url we are looking for is http://localhost:3000/ in frontend and the products is got from the backend using http://localhost:5000/api/products

Comment: Actually the images are not stored in the urls , the direct paths are stored in the database,when the products are fetched the image field will now be having the path to the image stored in the Folder of the project . Then the corresponding image is fetched , So the image url is not just the template , it is the actual url stored in the mongoDb database. And the upload function works such a way that in the project folder images are pushed in the uploads folder so that relative path is stored in database then tried to retrieve. But the images from the  uploads folder is not being retrieved

Comment: Actually the problem is simple , /images/mouse.jpg is accessable why not the /uploads/image-1647229113730.jpeg, though both are there in the projects folder

Comment: I have no idea what your last comment means.  `express.static()` works by matching the path from an incoming URL with a file in your file system.  That's ALL it can do.  It can't do anything with your database.  So, I've asked once already to see EXACTLY what URL you are putting in the web page that causes the browser to request that from your server.   We have to see the generated HTML that the browser sees in order to know what that is.  You can do View/Page Source in your browser to see the generated HTML.  I repeat.  `express.static()` will not do anything with your database.

Comment: Add this to your server: `console.log(path.join(__dirname, "/uploads"))` and see exactly what that is.  I think it's probably not pointing to the right place.  If `__dirname` is your `backend` directory, then you would need `app.use("/uploads", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../uploads")));` to get `express.static()` to be looking in the proper directory.  We also need to know exactly  what URL the browser is requesting too.

Comment: I totally get it ,but i just want to know how to make the /uploads/image-1647229113730.jpeg work and it isn't related to the database

Comment: You can see what URL the browser is requesting by adding this middleware as your first middleware: `app.use((req, res, next) => { console.log(req.path); next();})`

Comment: Hmm, I see you also  apparently have two servers on two different ports (3000 and 5000).  You also need to make sure the front-end is requesting the image from the right server.

Comment: Path is E:\Source Codes\GitHub\Web Developement\MernStack\uploads, And MernStack is my Main repository which contains backend,frorntend,uploads

Comment: the request is fetched perfectly , but now i begin to wonder how can even the first url work, /images/mouse.jpg , Because the Component Product which is setting the image src is in frontend/src/components/Product.js ; How can this acess frontend/public/images/mouse.jpg using /images/mouse.jpg. A small help would be highly appreciated. If i understand this i can work on how to make the upload path work

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by manually creating a variable named `__dirname` and assigned it the value of `path.resolve()` see example below

```js
import path from 'path';
const __dirname = path.resolve();
app.use("/uploads", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/uploads")));
```

and this solved the problem..

Answer (score -2):

In your server.js you are declaring __dirname which overrides the implicitly declared __dirname that node provides for you.

So instead of using the value of path.resolve() which is the current working directory as described [here](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathresolvepaths) you shouldn't declare __dirname yourself and use the __dirname that node provides. That is the path where your source file
is located.

Then you can use path.join(__dirname,'../uploads') to get the path of your uploads folder. (The two dots are important)

EDIT:

I'm sorry. I've completely forgotten that __dirname isn't available in ES modules...

But here is another way that could work:

```js
import { URL } from 'url';
const __dirname = new URL('.', import.meta.url).pathname;

app.use("/uploads", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../uploads")));
```

Comment: ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined in ES module scope

Comment: Not working even after updating the __dirname